# File Upload not an option when creating a column in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I am creating a new column in SharePoint for attachments. To setup this new column the type of information needs to be "File Upload", yet I don't have that as an option. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can just enable/disable attachment for list, while you could custom list form for users to upload attachments instead of OOB ribbon.

[image]

Here are two demo threads.

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/07/add-attachment-field-in-sharepoint-2013-list-form.html https://prashobjp.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/sharepoint-attachment-field-in-list-forms/